# Line break not working in jquery ui tooltip

Tags: php, tooltip, line, break

i was used this code
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking

i have to show the tooltip line by line

ex: -  This is <"\n or br"> the sample text

Result This is
 
       the sample text

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Look at http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content

> String: A string of HTML to use for the tooltip content.

So just add `<br>` as a Linebreake;

Comment: Why got this downrated? Prior edit of the question this was the best answer one could get without providing any of the used code.